# Kotlin override WebView

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin.

I try to create custom Error page in WebView.

Something like this in onCreate:

```
myWebView.webViewClient = WebViewClient() {
    override fun onReceivedError(
        view: WebView?,
        request: WebResourceRequest?,
        error: WebResourceError?
    ) {
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html")
    }
}
```

If I try this outside onCreate:

```
override fun onReceivedHttpError (view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest, errorResponse: WebResourceResponse) {
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html")
}
```

I got this error: **"overrides nothing"**

Can someone help me to the right direction?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onRecievedError` is deprecated

I think what you want is this

```
myWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
   
   override fun onReceivedHttpError (view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest, errorResponse: WebResourceResponse) {
       view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html")
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got this error: **Expecting member declaration**

Comment: you are referencing `myWebView` but the variable in the parameter is called `view`. So change  `myWebView`  to `view`

Comment: You also need to remove the `onReceivedError` method and replace it with this `onReceivedHttpError` method

Comment: Thanks, but still not working. The problem is, that I do not know where to put `override fun onReceivedHttpError (view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest, errorResponse: WebResourceResponse) { view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html") }` - I got different errors everywhere

Comment: The problem was, I needed to write like this: `myWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() { ... }` - Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad you sorted it! I'll update my answer again for anyone else :)

Answer (score 1):

You can go through this dependency.
https://github.com/mgks/Kotlin-SmartWebView

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to use default WebView with custom error page.

Comment: depend on the response you can show the error page also.